# Extend Core Js File in magento2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, extend

I want to extend vendor/magento/Magento_Customer/view/frontend/web/js/address/js to my custom module.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can extend it simply:

```
Vendor/moudlename/view/frontend/web/js/address/js
```

`You must remove static content e.g`:
`1) remove pub/static/frontend/*` 
`2) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
`3) php bin/magento cache:flush`